# Android 2.1 Native Lock Bitmap Pixels

Tags: java, android, bitmap, native, pixel

I'm running a basic native function that modifies the pixels of a bitmap. To do this I am getting the pixels via the Bitmap_lockPixels() function. However, this isn't available for versions lower than 2.2.

How do you recommend I replace this function to retain as much speed as possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can find almost similar solution here.This function used ReentrantLock Object and tries to get a lock.
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/android/src/com/opencv/camera/NativeProcessor.java?rev=3652

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a way to get the bitmap data pointer in native code, but this solves my problem for the lock itself.

Comment: Internally Bitmap_lockPixels() is also  doing the same thing.So you can generalize the code for irregardless of the platform

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. Would this allow me to access the bitmap data pointer in any way? That's really the main function I am using lockPixels for, not the locking.

Comment: I'm getting 403 Permission Denied on that page.